# How does drafting work in The Champion of the Wild?

Tags: untagged

We bought a copy of [The Champion of the Wild first edition](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1321865567/the-champion-of-the-wild), and totally missed the [second edition funding campaign](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1321865567/the-champion-of-the-wild-second-edition/).  One of the new things in the second edition is four new game modes involving drafting.

It looks like these should be playable with the first edition set, but we couldn't find details of the rules. In particular does the drafting happen before or after the events are revealed?  Or maybe are the two things interleaved, with some events being revealed at different stages of the draft?  Is this the same for all of the four variants?